# Check Backup was created

Tags: java, database, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to learn JSP/Servlets... I managed to write a function that takes a backup of the whole database...

```
package com.functions;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.sql.Connection;
//import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
//import java.sql.ResultSet;
//import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import com.functions.utility.DBConnector;

public class addMarks3 extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8097085789553030042L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {       

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println(" On Backup.java ");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

            fetchDataFromDB(request,response);
    }

    private void fetchDataFromDB(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){


        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            File backupFile = new File("C:/Users/Rohan/Desktop/LMS/backup.sql");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(backupFile);
            Process child = runtime.exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/mysqldump --user=root --password=root --lock-all-tables --opt dummy");
            InputStreamReader irs = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(irs);

            String line;
            while( (line=br.readLine()) != null ) {
                fw.write(line + "\n");
            }
            fw.close();
            irs.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I still cant figure out how to verify if the backup was successful..??
As in how do i check if the backup was succesfull or not.

PS: The file does get populated everytime i run it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.Check for the file sizes.

```
 File backupFile = new File("C:/Users/Rohan/Desktop/LMS/backup.sql");
 int len1=backupFile.length();
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(backupFile);

 Process child = runtime.exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/mysqldump --user=root --password=root --lock-all-tables --opt dummy");
        InputStreamReader irs = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(irs);
        String line;
        while( (line=br.readLine()) != null ) {
            fw.write(line + "\n");
        }
        fw.close();
        irs.close();
        br.close(); 

       int len2=backupFile.length();

       int compare=len2-len1;

          if(compare>0)
          {
            System.out.println("-- Backup done---");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the file gets populated everytime, doesn't that mean that the backup was successful?

Have you considered either streaming the process stream to the response stream?